# Run container without assigning a public IP using devops

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud, devops

I want to run a docker container (using Bluemix DevOps Services) without assigning a public IP. Wondering how to do that...its always assigning a public IP.

Thx

Comment: Please provide more information about how you are setting up your container and the environment you are using.

Comment: I am using the builder and deployer provided by the IBM DevOps Services. The deployer lets me configure the port I want to publish, e.g. 80, but I dont need one. And I dont need a public IP. But I can not configure it. Maybe there is a flag in the deployment options?

Answer (score 2):

The current default deploy script (you can see the git in the script box) for a single container is https://github.com/Osthanes/deployscripts/blob/master/deploycontainer.sh

Looking at that, the port field is optional, but if not set, it defaults it to 80, like you're seeing.  Simplest solution would be to point it to an unused port and ignore it, or you could fork the script and modify the git to clone your fork instead.

To not assign a public ip - one way is to switch from the default 'red_black' deployment strategy to 'simple'.  A side effect is that simple does not clean up the previous deploy, so if you want it to still do that, add an additional instance of the job on that same stage, with the strategy set to 'clean', and that will remove old instances.  As before, if you choose to fork the scripts, you can change that behavior in yours to whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

The public IP when you create a container on the IBM container service is optional.

You only need to bind the IP when you want to use it from the Internet.

What tool in devops are you using a maybe it is missing an option.

Ralph

Comment: I am using the Deployer Type "IBM Containers on Bluemix". But the port 80 seems to be mandatory...I can not delete it.